# Mule API Bulk Delete Using Database Connector and Returning Affected Rows

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am working on a flow that takes a payload (multiple contacts) and deletes them from a Postgres database. I am using a bulk mode for efficiency and this is currently working as expected.

[image]

When I have been working with single payload inputs in the past, I can get the row count response `0/1` after the delete and return an appropriate payload based on that.

My problem is when using bulk mode, it is returning an array of success/fails for the delete: ie `[1,1,1,0]` indicating that three records were deleted but one failed.

How could I approach this so I could return additional data in the response, such as the payload that failed to insert?

**Example Input:**

```
[{
    "contactId": "ABC123",
    "sourceOrgId": "12345"
},
{
    "contactId": "DEF567",
    "sourceOrgId": "67890"
}]
```

**Example Desired Output:**

```
[{
    "contactId": "ABC123",
    "sourceOrgId": "12345",
    "status": 0
},
{
    "contactId": "DEF567",
    "sourceOrgId": "67890",
    "status": 1
}]
```

In the desired output, I would know which records from the original payload were deleted successfully and which ones failed to delete.

Can something like this be done when using bulk mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can join two payloads - one for input and one as result

%

```
dw 2.0
output text/json
var payload1=[{
    "contactId": "ABC123",
    "sourceOrgId": "12345"
},
{
    "contactId": "DEF567",
    "sourceOrgId": "67890"
}]
var payload2=[1,9]
---
payload1 map ( item, index ) -> (
    item ++ {status:payload2[index]}
)
```

output is

```
[
  {
    "contactId": "ABC123",
    "sourceOrgId": "12345",
    "status": 1
  },
  {
    "contactId": "DEF567",
    "sourceOrgId": "67890",
    "status": 9
  }
]
```

[image]

Look here for details https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/MergeArraysItems.html